# How to use the Blueimp jquery file uploader in rails 4 with mongoid (Mongo DB)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, file-upload

I am looking for a solution how to use Blueimp jquery file uploader using rails 4 with mongoid . I have tried this solution [jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails-paperclip-example) But this is for active records.

Comment: The jquery part is not your problem, paperclip is. Google how to use paperclip with mongodb and you shall find your answer.

Comment: I have added the paperclip for mongoid but it's giving some javascript error TypeError: fu._adjustMaxNumberOfFiles is not a function